"Always On" requests blocked by Easy Auth on Azure App Service
We have a web app, where Easy Auth is configured on the app service like in the image. So all requests must be authorized.

We have also enabled the "Always On" feature on the web app, because we want to keep the underlying website alive always.
However, we can see in the AppServiceHTTPLogs log table, that the requests from the AlwaysOn user agent are receiving a 401 status code.
Our application is not responding with the 401, so the Always On request must be getting rejected by the Easy Auth feature.
I looked at this post How to ensure "Always On" App Service starts automatically behind Azure AD which claims that setting the WEBSITE_WARMUP_PATH to / would bypass the Easy Auth for that url, but that changed nothing. Also, we still want normal requests to the root to be authorized, but we want the Always On requests to be allowed to actually hit the application.
How to we achieve this?
The application is dotnet, running on a linux app service plan, if that makes any difference.

Please share more details about the issue.

@Harshitha which details are you missing?

I created a sample ASP .Net Web API application and deployed it to Azure web app (Linux).

To avoid the error, I've created an API controller in my application.
Thanks to @AndyP.dev I've referred this doc and added [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the warmup method.
This allows the Always On requests to succeed without being blocked by Easy Auth.

WarmupController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WarmupController : ControllerBase
{
   requests.
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("warmup")]
    public IActionResult Warmup()
    {
        return Ok("App is warmed up");
    }
}

After deploying the app to Azure Web App, set the environment variable to warmup route as shown below.

Here's the output without any errors:




Are you sure that the website is receiving request with the AlwaysOn user agent? Always On and Warmup are two different things, and from what I can tell, the Always On always makes request to the root url.

Thanks for your feedback. my approach is focused on ensuring the app stays warm and responsive through a warmup route that bypasses Easy Auth. If you're specifically looking to address the root URL issue for "Always On," Will review the implementation and update you accordingly.
